# Google Glass - screen won't appear after update

Tags: android, google-glass

Now that XE16 is available, I decided to update my Glass with the new [boot.img](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system). Everything looked like it succeeded, but when I restarted the Glass, the main screen doesn't appear. When I try to use adb commands, it says my device is unauthorized and that I should check the appropriate dialog.

I'd love to check the dialog, but as I said, the screen won't appear.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mismatched boot.img? Try either building the kernel or extracting it from the factory system image (assuming you tested that image).

As for building, the instructions reference glass-omap-xrr02 but the latest accessible one is glass-omap-xrv34 (for XE17).  update: glass-omap-xrv60b XE17.2